# python open an access database with pyodbc

Tags: python, ms-access, dsn

I am trying to open a MS Access Database with python :

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\file.accdb') 
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from Table1')
```

but I get this error :`

InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')`

MS Access and Python are both in 64bit and by looking closer I discovered that my available DSN is an Adaptative Server Client and I do not have Microsoft access Driver

Does anyone know how I can make the connection?

Comment: _my available DSN is an Adaptative Server Client_ What does this mean? Do you have 64-bits access installed on the same machine as you're running the Python code on, or not? It should come with an ODBC driver, if it doesn't, you have an installation issue (for a short period some versions of Office 365 shipped without it and required separate installation of the database engine).

Comment: Hi Erik sorry for the misunderstanding, I have 64-bits access installed and the ODBC driver, I specify this because I used the function pyodbc.dataSources() and it returns : 'ASA 9.0 Client Sample': 'Adaptive Server Anywhere 9.0',
 'ASA 9.0 Sample': 'Adaptive Server Anywhere 9.0'

but no Microsoft access Driver

Comment: `pyodbc.dataSources()` is irrelevant to this problem. Check `pyodbc.drivers()`. I highly doubt you have the Access ODBC driver installed with matched bitness, since the error states you haven't.

Comment: Hi Erik, following your comment the function return this :
pyodbc.drivers()

['SQL Server', 'Adaptive Server Anywhere 9.0']

Comment: @Aarcko - You may need to install the Access Database Engine Redistributable separately. Details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/cannot-use-odbc-or-oledb).